# Official Snowflake ODBC driver is extremely slow in transferring result sets to on-prem SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're needing to switch from hosting our own local database to using a Snowflake-hosted instance of the same database going forward for all of our queries going forward in my company, but I'm running into one large roadblock at the moment.

Snowflake's execution speed is significantly faster than equivalently heavy queries being run natively against our local database, so that's great. The problem I'm facing is actually sending results from Snowflake queries back to our local SQL Server to then be transformed and inserted into some local reference tables. The transfer rate, per-row, is prohibitively slow.

A big query might execute in less than a minute in Snowflake but then take hours to actually send over to our server, and I suspect that the limitation lies within the official ODBC driver itself. Our server itself has a gigabit fiber connection, and I've confirmed with my IT team that there is no speed throttling being applied at the firewall level.

I think it's the driver because when I run the same queries in Power BI Desktop, using its inbuilt Snowflake connector, it shows a much faster rate of retrieval on the same network connection.

- In Power BI I'm seeing 1 million rows in 2:06
- In SQL via ODBC I'm getting 275k rows in 4:11

This is for a simple select top 1000000 * from [table] query, so this is pure data transfer time being measured here.

I've looked around to see if there's some fetch size variable I can alter for the Snowflake ODBC driver to no avail. Doesn't seem like there is one. Has anyone here run into something like this before and found a solution? I'd be extremely grateful for any insight on this issue.

I tried running simple queries to return > 1 million rows from Snowflake using the EXECUTE AT SQL command against a linked server using the official Snowflake ODBC driver.

I was expecting the 1 million-row result set to be retrieved in a matter of seconds.

What happened was it took over four minutes to return about 1/4 of the total rows being queried.

Comment: Snowflake's ODBC driver should transfer rows orders of magnitude faster than you're reporting here. One of the more likely reasons for this is some kind of security device on the on-prem network. If the result set is over a specific size, Snowflake's back end instructs the clients (ODBC included) to download compressed files from the cloud host and process them locally. Sometimes security devices on networks block this entirely, and sometimes they interfere with normal transfer and make the transfer slow. You may want to check with your network team and also open a Support case with Snowflake.

Comment: A little more information is needed. What are all of the components of the data pipeline from Snowflake to SQL Server? Are you using C# code, Python, Java, Alteryx, or what?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I'm going to set up a meeting with our IT team soon to confirm that there's nothing related to the security configuration on our server that might be inhibiting or slowing down the loading of the compressed files into SQL Server. As for my pipeline, in this case there is none. I'm simply running OPENQUERY statements in SSMS against my Snowflake linked server connection via the official ODBC driver.

Comment: "a million rows" doesn't really tell us how much data is being transferred. Is it 10 columns of `bit`, or 1,000 columns of `char(8000)`?

Comment: Generally speaking... TDS (the client-server protocol used by Microsoft SQL Server) was designed over thirty years ago for use on low latency LAN environments and, because it's so chatty, performs horribly over higher latency WAN environments. i.e.: You might have a gigabit connection to the internet, but if it's >=200ms latency between you and the target SQL server it's going to be really painful transferring rowsets on a row-by-row basis. Do you have other options for transferring the data, e.g.: gzipped JSON or XML files over HTTP/S?

Answer (score 0):

The native connector in Azure Synapse to Snowflake worked fast. however it does not support writes to snowflake if Snowflake is hosted on AWS, so we had to install a custom IR and a Snowflake ODBC connector. The slowdown with the same data was 10X, but you can run 4-5 parallel processes on Azure Synapse (ir more if you have more CORES than we =2) . Eventually we got test data (250MB) in 3 min over versus seconds using Azure Synapse connector.
It could be that AWS region makes a difference and not ODBC. it is beter to host all on one platform (in our case azure) including snowflake. in our case we had no choice.